# Exclude one pattern from glob match

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have several files with the same base filename. I'd like to remove all but one

```
foo.org #keep
foo.tex #delete
foo.fls #delete
foo.bib #delete
etc
```

If I didn't need to keep one, I know I could use `rm foo.*`.

[TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) demonstrates `^` to negate a match. Through trial and error, I was able to find that

```
rm foo.*[^org]
```

does what I need, but I don't really understand the syntax.

Also, while not a limitation in my use case, I think this pattern also ignores `foo.o` and `foo.or`. How does this pattern work, and what would a glob that ignores *only* `foo.org` look like?

Comment: As an addition to @glen answer it is worth to mention that `rm foo.*[^org]` removes all files which **last** character is neither `o`, `r` or `g`, so `foo.foo` wouldn't match either.

Comment: You are using a `Regular Expression`.  You should be careful with your grouping characters.  By using brackets you've specified a character class meaning that you would delete any files that had an extension with the letters `o`,`r` or `g` in any order.  Use parenthesis to create a group and preserve the order of characters.

Comment: @jbarker2160 - that's not really a regular expression, it's more commonly called a _glob_ (or _filename pattern_), which is more or less a subset of a regular expression - see the pattern matching section of the bash manpage for details. His pattern `foo.*[^org]` will match any filename that begins with `foo.` with one or more characters after the dot where the last character is not o, r, or g.  So it would match `foo.orb`, but not `foo.org` or `foo.or` or `foo.o`. GlennJackman's answer shows how to enable extended pattern matching features to negate a match.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
echo rm foo.!(org)
```

This matches `foo.` followed by anything NOT `org`

To restore normal glob behavior afterwards, use:

```
shopt -u extglob
```

Reference: [The GNU Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: I tried doing the same but with brackets and apparently when using brackets it does not work

Comment: What is the syntax to match multiple file names? say I want to exclude .org, .png, .txt ?

Comment: @Freedo `@()` for a pattern-list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/217208/3779853

Comment: is there a way to do the same when using /bin/sh?

Comment: For plain sh, I'd use a for-loop with a case statement inside to decide which files to keep.

Answer (score 43):

In bash, you can also use `GLOBIGNORE="*.org"; rm -i foo*`.

And `unset GLOBIGNORE` when done.

It's not really better than `shopt -s extglob`, but I find it easier to remember.

Comment: @Ruslan That doesn't work. You should do `( GLOBIGNORE="*.org"; rm -i foo* )`

Comment: Note if you want to expand the list of ignored, separate with a colon, such as `GLOBIGNORE="*foo*:*bar*"`

Comment: Hmmm I ended up needing to add a `&&` between setting the GLOBIGNORE and the command following where it is supposed to be applied. I assume that if you don't, the entire expression is evaluated and all * snippets are expanded - at which point it is too late to set GLOBIGNORE. In other words, for this example: `GLOBIGNORE="*.org" && rm -i foo*`

Comment: Thank you @consideRatio for the explanation. So that's why the subshell and semicolon were suggested by DBedrenko. The OP simply doesn't work and any version that does work leaves you an environment variable to clean up.

Answer (score 14):

A pipe can do?

```
ls * | grep -v "foo.org" | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

(obviously you might want to replace echo with rm in the last chain).

Comment: Useful if needed in just one line.

Comment: Easier to remember (for me, I do that sort of thing often) and allows more complex processing to boot :)

Comment: `ls -1` should be more reliable to ensure all files are handled by `grep` separately

Comment: Unfortunately, the side-effect of `xargs` in this form is that each process (and therefore file) waits to complete before the next process runs.  So, in the case of something like `xz -T0` multithreaded compression will be limited to within the file which reduces the efficiency considerably on multicore systems.  You can add the `-P` flag to xargs which helps, but still means the compression indexes have to be rebuilt separately for every file.

Comment: @MichaelChirico We have `find` for that, *never* parse ls output.

Comment: Note that `ls *` would list the contents of any directory matching `*`. It would also delete any file whose name does _not_ match `foo.*`.

Comment: In almost every case `echo *` is preferable to `ls *`, when scripting.  One problem with `echo *` is that it doesn't hit hidden files.  `echo * .*` does that.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern `foo.*[^org]`, which is properly written `foo.*[!org]` (but `bash` can use `^` in place of `!`) would match any name that starts with `foo.` and ends in something that is not `o`, `r` or `g`.  The `[...]` bit always matches exactly one single character.  This would not match `foo.org` as it ends with `g`, but it would also not match `foo.log` for the same reason.

A portable answer would be to use a loop, and then to avoid acting on the file that we want to keep:

```bsh
for name in foo.*; do [ "$name" != foo.org ] && rm -- "$name"; done
```

If you want to avoid deleting any file matching `foo.*` and ending in `.org` (e.g. `foo.org` or `foo.beef.org` etc.), then consider using a second pattern match like so:

```bsh
for name in foo.*; do case $name in (*.org) continue;; esac; rm -- "$name"; done
```

Using `find` instead, the first loop above would be equivalent to

```bsh
find . ! -path . -prune -name 'foo.*' ! -name foo.org -exec rm {} +
```

while the second one would be the same as

```bsh
find . ! -path . -prune -name 'foo.*' ! -name '*.org' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: Find with `! -name` works really well!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish.  Suppose that you have some file `foo.sh` that you want exclude from your operation, yet you want to add `csv` to every other file.  You could use the following loop:

```
for f in *; do
  if [ "${f: -3}" != ".sh" ]; then
    mv "$f" "${f%}.csv"
  fi
done
```

Comment: This seems to be an answer to some related question about renaming files, but the current question asks about removing files.