# How to copy using for loop?

Tags: command-line, files, cp

I am using this 
`for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && cp -R ../lib . ); done` 
in a shell script to copy lib folder in all subfolder inside my parent directory . But the lib folder also getting copied inside lib . How to avoid that ?

Comment: Would `cp -R lib "$d"/` do, leaving the `cd` and subshell unnecessary?

Comment: Similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `extglob`:

```
for d in */ ; do
    if [ "$d" != "lib/" ]; then
        cp -R lib "$d"
    fi
done
```

Or just delete it afterwards... (well, unless `lib/lib` exists beforehand!)

```
for d in */; do cp -R lib "$d"; done
rm -r lib/lib
```

(Somewhat amusingly, GNU cp says `cp: cannot copy a directory, 'lib', into itself, 'lib/lib'`, but does it anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
shopt -s extglob
for d in ./!(lib)/; do #...
```

Or maybe move it out so it doesn't match:

```
mv lib ../ #better not have a conflicting ../lib directory there
for d in */; do cp -R ../lib "$d"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the does-not-include option of ls command:

```
for d in $(ls -I lib -1 */) ; do cp -R lib "$d" ; done
```

Comment: That `ls` will list all the files in the subdirectories (it's what it does when given a directory on the command line), and it won't ignore `lib` because it's given on the command line, through the glob (try `ls -l -I lib lib`). And parsing ls like that will burn if you have filenames with spaces.

Comment: you could get close with `ls -I lib .` or `ls -d -I lib */`, but you get either regular files too (which `*/` doesn't give), or `lib/` too (since it's in the glob).

Comment: You're right but I have expected that there are only directories in the current path.