# Copying files in bash

Tags: command-line, cp, file-copy

I want to copy all files (included sub-folders) from `$HOME` directory to `Desktop` in bash. And as you know the `Desktop` is in `$HOME`. So, when I copy all files I get the message like this:

`cannot copy a directory, '/home/adminuser/Desktop', into itself, '/home/adminuser/Desktop/'`.

And I don't know the suitable code to exclude the folder `Desktop`.
I use this: `cp -r $HOME/* ~/Desktop/`

Does anybody know a code for it or can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you actually _mean_ copy, or do you mean move? Just asking because it's more common to want to move files around rather than duplicating them...

Comment: Possibly related: [Exclude one pattern from glob match](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match)

Comment: Yes, i mean copy

Answer (score 1):

Use `rsync`

```
rsync -av --progress $HOME/* $HOME/Desktop --exclude 'Desktop/'
```

Comment: This would also exclude hidden files

Comment: Done. Now it will exclude only dirs called `Desktop/`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using `rsync`:

```
rsync -avWxP --exclude Desktop /home/user/ /home/user/Desktop/
```