# How to find all files except a specified file

Tags: wildcards

The `ls` can give a result like

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# ls
```

> `CentOS-Base.repo  CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Media.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo`

But actually I hope to just find out `CentOS-Base.repo`，`CentOS-Debuginfo.repo` and `CentOS-Vault.repo` but not `CentOS-Media.repo`.
So I run this command

```
ls [^\(Media\)]
```

But I get a error information.How should I do?

Comment: Related: [Exclude one pattern from glob match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your link,that is very usefull for me..

Comment: You might consider switching your shell to [zsh](http://zsh.org/), which has a [pattern removal](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#subst) facility

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most simple case you may use the following (in case if the 1st subword is static `CentOS`):

```
ls CentOS-[BDV]*
```

---

- `[BDV]` - character class to ensure the second subword starting with one of the specified characters

or the same with *negation*:

```
ls CentOS-[^M]*
```

---

If you want to ignore all filenames that contain the `M` character, with the GNU implementation of `ls` (as typically found on CentOS), use the `-I` (`--ignore`) option:

```
ls -I '*M*'
```

> **-I, --ignore**=*PATTERN*
>  do not list implied entries matching shell *PATTERN*

To ignore entries with `Media` word:

```
ls -I '*Media*'
```

Those patterns need to be passed verbatim to `ls`, so must be quoted (otherwise, the shell would treat them as globs to expand).

Comment: Why we cannot use `ls *[^M]*`？

Comment: The `ls CentOS-[^M]*` work,but the `ls *[^M]*` don't..

Comment: @yode, depends on what exactly you want to ignore: `M` character occurence OR `Media` word?

Comment: But in my case,only that file have a charater `M`.

Comment: @yode, see my notation in the answer

Comment: Thanks your answer very very much,though I think the `ls *[^M]*` should work here still.

Comment: The patterns are greedy: the first * matches everything except the last letter, the [^M] matches the last letter since none of them ends with M and the trailing * matches the empty string. So they all match. And even if something ended with M, it would still match, assuming there was something different from M somewhere: e.g. if you had a file called OOM, the first star would match the first O, the [^M] would match the second O and the trailing start would match the M.

Answer (score 12):

A few shells have negation globbing operators:

- `zsh -o extendedglob`:

  ```
  ls -d -- ^*Media*
  ls -d -- *.repo~*Media* # ~ is "except" operator
  ```
- `ksh`, `zsh -o kshglob`, `bash -O extglob`:

  ```
  ls -d -- !(*Media*)
  ```
- `bash`:

  ```
  GLOBIGNORE='*Media*'
  ls -d -- *
  ```
- `ksh`:

  ```
  FIGNORE='@(*Media|.)*'
  ls -d -- *
  ```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to use find.
Do:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "CentOS-Media.repo"
```

Here "f" means search for *regular files* only (excludes symlinks to regular files though; with GNU `find`, use `-xtype f` instead to include them). If you want to search for directories, pass "d" instead.

(`-maxdepth` while initially a GNU extension is now quite common. If your `find` doesn't support it, you can replace `-maxdepth 1` with the standard `! -name . -prune`).

see the [find man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for more awesome features.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use `find` with the `-not -name`  flags. I.e. `find . -not -name CentOS-Media.repo`. If you don't want to recurse down the directory structure, add `-maxdepth 1` flag.

Alternatively, one may write the following (which is much more complex, but I forgot about `-not` flag and posted this answer originally, so I will not delete this part):

`find . -print0 | grep  --invert-match -z "CentOS-Media.repo$" | tr '\0' '\n'`

You need to force `find` to separate filenames with null byte, so that newlines in filenames won't break anything down. Hopefully, `grep` supports this kind of separator with flag `-z`. You may want to revert to the typical separation (i.e. null byte ->  new line) with `tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: You can also get null-separated filenames with `printf '%s\0' *` which doesn't recurse and doesn't include dotfiles by default (but some shells have an option for that). You also don't need `-E` for _that_ regexp, but to be picky you should either backslash the `.` or put it in `[]`, and you do depend on _GNU_ find and grep.