# Bash for loop on all files in folder except one

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

I have a folder filled with 9 Robot Framework test files. Only 8 of them have to be executed, as the last one is used to set up all the others (let's call it `config.robot`).

If I had to run all those tests I would have done something like

```
for test_file in folder/*.robot; do
    robot -b debug.log -d log/ $test_file.robot;
done
```

but in this case it means that `config.robot` will also be run, which I don't want.

**How could I perform a for loop on all files in folder except one?**

If that helps, all files except `config.robot` respect the following naming syntax: they all start with their execution order and are followed by their actual name, e.g. `01__init-connection.robot`.

---

**Edit:** Before posting that question I had already seen and tried the answers offered in [Exclude one pattern from glob match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match) and wrote something similar to

```
shopt -s extglob
for test_file in folder/!(config).robot; do ...
```

But Robot Framework does not recognize the file name:

```
Parsing 'folder/!(config).robot' failed: Data source does not exist.
```

so I guess that Robot Framework doesn't like that syntax.
I'm thinking about setting a variable with the results of a find according to a regex matching my filename structure and then performing the for loop on the variable:

```
SUITES=$(find . -regex '^[0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z_-]*')
for SUITE in $SUITES; do robot -b ...
```

But for some reason when I `echo` SUITES it returns nothing. I don't know what I missed here.

Comment: Related: [exclude a file from a glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match/164026)

Comment: @avazula, if you get the pattern literally back from a glob, it means the pattern didn't match anything (and you didn't have nullglob or failglob set). You may want to check the exact commands you run and the files you have to see that they actually match. E.g. try what `touch foo.robot bar.robot config.robot; shopt -s extglob; for f in ./!(config).robot; do echo "file: $f"; done` does in an empty directory, it should print the names of `foo.robot` and `bar.robot`.

Comment: GNU `find` has its peculiar approach to regular expressions. It supports several regex types, defaulting to `emacs`. Also, note that `find` regular expressions must match whole paths, not just file names. For instance, if you are familiar with BRE, and assuming your files are in `./folder` (relative to the current directory), you may use `find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '\./folder/[0-9]\{2\}[-A-Za-z_]\{1,\}\.robot'`. Nevertheless, this approach is really fragile and not advisable. Getting globbing right is the way to go.

Comment: Regarding you edit: You tagged the question with [tag:bash].  If this is not what your framework thingy uses, then please figure out what shell it uses and re-tag the question appropriately.  Jeff's answer is correct for `bash`.

Comment: Any other shell than Bash would probably not have `shopt`, and the parenthesis in the glob would likely be a syntax error if extended globs weren't supported. (Except that it seems a valid glob in Zsh, but then Zsh would by default complain  about a glob that didn't match anything so there wouldn't be an error from `robot`.)

Comment: @avazula, I just saw your updated post -- 8 months later! -- and updated my answer to help explain why you had those results.

Answer (score 5):

In bash, as tagged:

```
shopt -s extglob
for test_file in folder/!(config).robot; do robot -b debug.log -d log/ "$test_file".robot; done
```

---

In response to the update:

> ```
> shopt -s extglob
> for test_file in folder/!(config).robot; do ...
> ```

resulting in:

> Parsing 'folder/!(config).robot' failed: Data source does not exist.

This could happen if there are no ".robot" files in "folder" besides "config.robot". Consider:

```
$ mkdir folder
$ touch folder/config.robot
$ shopt -s extglob
$ shopt -u nullglob
$ for f in folder/!(config).robot; do ls --- "$f"; done
ls: cannot access folder/!(config).robot: No such file or directory
```

Versus (a fresh start):

```
$ mkdir folder
$ touch folder/config.robot
$ shopt -s extglob
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for f in folder/!(config).robot; do ls -- "$f"; done
$
```

Where the `for` loop does not execute any commands because the wildcard did not expand to any files.

Or the alternative, where there **are** non-config.robot files there:

```
$ mkdir folder
$ touch folder/config.robot
$ touch folder/01__init-connection.robot
$ shopt -s extglob
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for f in folder/!(config).robot; do ls -- "$f"; done
folder/01__init-connection.robot
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `continue` command.

Also note that the variable picks up the whole path.

```sh
for f in folder/*.robot; do
    test "$f" = folder/config.robot && continue 
    robot -b debug.log -d log/ "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```bsh
for test_file in folder/*.robot; 
do 
    [ "$test_file" != "config.robot" ] && robot -b debug.log -d log/ $test_file.robot;
done
```

- `robot` will run only if `$test_file` is not equal to `config.robot`

or simple using `find`

```bsh
find folder/*.robot ! -name "config.robot" -exec robot -b debug.log -d log/ {} +
```

Comment: Using `extglob` (as in @sparhawk comment) is more efficient...

Comment: @xenoid, efficient in what way? If you mean in terms of CPU time used, the difference is quite likely to be totally negligible. If you mean in terms of readability or such, do note that not everyone might be familiar with ksh-style extended globs, and they're not standard anyway, unlike the `if` solution

Comment: `find folder/*.robot ...` works but is a bit odd. You'd usually use `find . -name "*.robot" ! -name "config.robot" -exec ...` Of course, the latter would recurse to subdirectories, and would not keep the filenames in numerical order, while the former does exactly the opposite...

Comment: Fewer processes and shorter code. "*Not everyone can be familiar...*": yes, but everyone can/should learn a new trick from time to time otherwise we would still all be using the original `sh`. My skills improve because when I see some code I don't recognize, I try to understand where that comes from and if I can use it myself.